# Can't display C/C++ code correctly after adding/saving/inserting code into mysql table

Tags: mysql, html, database, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

code like that with < (left angle bracket)=>

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
```

It's displayed as =>

```
#include
#include
#include
```

code after <(left angle bracket) is deleted. Why does it occur?

posts table=>

```
mysql> describe posts;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| title       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| body        | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| category_id | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tags        | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| mark        | tinyint(4)   | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| created     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| modified    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: "View code" where? Seems it's not formatting it properly. Simple as. nothing to do with MySQL or C++. Click "view source" in your browser to see whether CakePHP is simply doing a poor job of displaying database contents.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, `echo $listposts['Post']['body'];` this displays C++ code without < , how can i get the correct formatting?

Comment: you sure that's not just your browser trying to render <> elements as HTML elements? MySQL should not do anything related - it's either they way you view the output, or you have strip_tags() playing somewhere in your DB related code.

Comment: @guru: No, it displays C++ code _with_ those symbols. Your browser thinks it's HTML, though. `<...>` is a "tag" in HTML. If you click "View Source" in your browser then you'll see the raw text. Either output as `text/plain`, or encode with `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Yes, i see that C++ code in 'Page View Source' but not in the web page , how can i output that code as text/plain?

Comment: @guru: We don't have enough information. If you want to display this C++ on a web page, encase it in `<pre>` tags or something. Search for information about escaping HTML.

Comment: If i output as htmlspecialchars(); the it also prints <br/>, so i can't get newline.

Comment: try a combination of `nl2br` and `h()` perhaps. (`h()` is a CakePHP convenience function shorthand for `htmlspecialchars()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you showed your output code from your view, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
echo htmlentities($listposts['Post']['body']);
```